# Using apache poi to get a slide id from a pptx

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I saw that there is a unique identifier for power point slides via
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.slideid

I don't see a way to access this slide id from apache poi. Am I just missing something or is it not possible?

Comment: So you are expecting that `apache poi` is a reimplementation of the `Microsoft PowerPoint object model`? No it is not. So it is not clear what `SlideID` you are talking about. If `Office Open XML` `*.pptx` is meant, then maybe `sldId (Slide ID)` in `sldIdLst (List of Slide IDs)` in presentation?

Comment: @AxelRichter ah ok i see. Yes this is it, thanks. If you set this up as an answer I can mark it.